# Tricky extension of java generic class

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to create a generic class from the following parent class:

```java
public class AVLTree<T extends Comparable> {
}
```

I have tried with the following

```java
public class ExtendedTree<T extends Comparable> extends AVLTree<T> {
}
```

But this doesn't event compile. Any idea what is the correct syntax ?

Comment: For me this code compiles.

Comment: what is the compilation error message?

Comment: `AVLTree<T extends Comparable<T>>`, in order that Comparable isn't raw.

Comment: Thanks Andy, you've got it ! The error was `Bound mismatch: The type T is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<T>> of the type 
  AVLTree<T>`

Comment: So actually code that you posted was not the one that caused the error...

Comment: Sorry @michalk. The code for AVLTree is from Apache commons library, and I took the copy/pasted the code from an old version on the internet. I understood later that my binary version is different. I copied ```public class AVLTree<T extends Comparable>```, whereas my binary version has ```public class AVLTree<T extends Comparable<T>>```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make you type variables self-bounded:

```
public class AVLTree<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

Or, better:

```
public class AVLTree<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

Similarly for your subclass.

Otherwise you are using `Comparable` as a raw type.